# Page 404 if page isn't found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project on Laravel 5.8. It's internet-market with categories, brands and products. I used in my controllers a variable from model:
route:

```
Route::prefix('categories')->get('/{category}', 'ProductsController@openCategory')->name('openCategory');
```

model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'category_alias';
    }
}
```

controller-method:

```
public function openCategory(Category $category = null)
{
    $allInfo = $this->getAllInfo();
    $categories = $this->getCategories();
    $brands = $this->getBrands();

    return view("pages.category", compact('allInfo','category', 'categories', 'brands'));
}
```

I don't use relation by ID, I use relation by 'category_alias'. But if I write category name with error, I get message - OPPS! We Couldn’t Find this Page
Uh... So it looks like you brock something. The page you are looking for has up and Vanished. Why? But if I use relation by ID, I get page 404 - it's success for me.

Answer (score 1):

By defining the route with ->get('/{category}' and typehinting on the controller, Category $category you are telling Laravel that you want it to resolve the category for you.

This is handled by the service container as described at https://laravel.com/docs/master/container#introduction

If you provide a value which doesn't resolve to the id for a category in the database, the service container will be be unable to load anything. Laravel responds to those scenarios by returning the 404.

Comment: Yeah, I have directory resources->views->errors->404.blade.php . Early I have got this page, but now I get this message: OPPS!...

Comment: I think, that because of prefix in routes...But I don't know how can I fix this problem

Comment: What is the exact message you are seeing? It is most likely indicating a 500 error. Is anything being logged in the storage/logs directory?

Comment: I have this message: OPPS! We Couldn’t Find this Page
Uh... So it looks like you brock something. The page you are looking for has up and Vanished.
Bring me back Home

Comment: Here is my project: https://github.com/AlexeyDanilov/E-Shopper
I have found nothing about this problem.